# Lombok Value annotation not working properly for Immutable java class

Tags: java, immutability, lombok

I was looking to see if it's possible to create an immutable Java class using Lombok. I found this page on the Lombok website "Immutable classes made very easy", but I'm not convinced by it: https://projectlombok.org/features/Value

I have tested it using the sample class they use in that page i.e.

```
@Value
public class ValueExample {
  String name;
  @With(AccessLevel.PACKAGE) @NonFinal int age;
  double score;
  protected String[] tags;
  
  @ToString(includeFieldNames=true)
  @Value(staticConstructor="of")
  public static class Exercise<T> {
    String name;
    T value;
  }
}
```

and wrote a little test:

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    String tags[] = {"a", "b", "c"};

    ValueExample t = new ValueExample("name", 1, 2.3, tags);

    System.out.println("BEFORE:" + Arrays.toString(t.getTags()));

    String[] tagsToModify = t.getTags();

    for (int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        tagsToModify[i] = "?";
    }

    System.out.println("AFTER: " + Arrays.toString(t.getTags()));
}
```

The output of the test is:

```
BEFORE:[a, b, c]
AFTER: [?, ?, ?]
```

which to me means the class in not immutable.
Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `tags` is an `Array`, hence a reference type, and arrays are mutable. While it is true that the you can't change the value of `tags` (e.g., you can't reassign it to reference a different array), the array it references can be mutated by whoever holds a reference to it (including the `ValueExample` class itself, or the `main` method you created to test this behaviour).

Leaving reflection aside for a moment (as it provides a "backdoor" that breaks immutability), for a class to be really immutable, all the referenced properties should be immutable too – and Array isn't – or you might have to resort to techniques like defensive copying.

As an additional note, you need to return immutable objects in your getters too. Imagine you make a defensive copy of the `tags` array in your constructor. If you return your copy in the `getTags()`, anyone who can call that getter will also be able to mutate the array (again, because arrays are mutable). So ideally you'd need to make a new copy in both the constructor and in the getter. If the array is big, this can easily become quite expensive... On top of that, each item in the array should be immutable too, otherwise anyone who has access to the array could mutate those objects too.